# LightDM crashes after logging into my account but works fine for all other accounts

Tags: unity, lightdm

I have Ubuntu 12.04.

I installed the kubuntu-desktop package from the software centre and the installation went fine. But after restarting, LightDM kept on crashing when I logged into my account. But when I tried for my mom's account it worked fine.

How do I solve this problem? Could it be a permission problem with the home folder?

Answer (score 0):

lightdm is the back-end for unity-greeter, and it runs as the root user, not as your user, so do you mean that Unity is crashing when you try to login?  If that's the case you can try unity-2d to login and then reset unity using this command:

```
unity --reset
```

If lightdm or unity-greeter is truly crashing then I'd need to see the contents of /var/log/lightdm/*.  Those logs will contain usernames from your system if that concerns you.

Comment: Unity 3D doesn't work for my nvidia card so I use unity 2d. But I solved my problem. I tried starting the unity 2d session manually using xinit. Reading the errors I found that my home folder was not readable. Some how home folder file permissions were changed. So I used:
`chown -R user:user /home/user`

to get the permissions back. And it started working. Anyway, thnx for you help